# Scala composition of partially-applied functions

Tags: scala, function, composition

I'd like to be able to compose functions from partially-applied functions. I.e. something like this:

```
def average(data: Seq[Option[Double]]): Option[Double] = {
  val numbers = data.flatten
  numbers match {
    case ns if ns.length == 0 => None
    case ns => Some(ns.sum / ns.length)
  }
}

def roundHalfUp(d: Double, rounding: Int): Double = {
  BigDecimal.apply(d).setScale(rounding, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue
}

def round(rounding: Int, number: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
  number match {
    case None => None
    case Some(n) => Some(roundHalfUp(n, rounding))
  }
}


val f = average andThen round(2)

f(List(1.23, 2.242, 3.345))
```

But I can't get the assignment of the composed function to work. I appreciate to coerce the functions I need parameter placeholders, i.e. `val f = average(_) andThen round(2,_)` but no matter what syntax I try doesn't work.

Could anyone advise on the correct syntax, or an alternative approach. This is supposed to be functionality for a simple design specific language so the simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out!

I need to define the round function like this:

```
def round(rounding: Int)(number: Option[Double]): Option[Double] = {
  number match {
    case None => None
    case Some(n) => Some(roundHalfUp(n, rounding))
  }
}
```

and then I can lift the methods to functions (using parameter _):

```
val r = round(2) _
val a = average _

val f = a andThen r

f(List(1.23, 2.242, 3.345))
```

Or, without the intermediat variables,

```
val f = (average _) andThen (round(2) _)
```

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that if I have the original definition of round, i.e. `round(rounding: Int, number: Option[Double])`, is that I can only get the function composition to work with brackets like this `val f = average _ andThen (round(2, _))`. I'd have thought the second set of brackets are unnecessary.

Comment: Basically Scala generally assumes that you don't actually want to partially apply, because making that assumption leads to counterintuitive behavior in conjunction with the more OO aspects of Scala's design.

Comment: From Odersky's _Programming in Scala_, section 8.7's sidebar "Why the trailing underscore?": In [languages such as ML or Haskell], partially applied functions are considered the normal case... [and] these languages have a type system [without subtyping and a universal base type, which] will usually highlight every error with partial applications you can make.  For example, say you mistook `drop(n: Int)` for `tail` and forgot to pass a number to `drop`.  You might write `println(list.drop)`: if partial application were assumed, this would type check[, though without the output you intended].

Comment: Scala will only assume partial application in situations where a function type is expected.  `val f: Seq[Option[Double]] => Option[Double] = (average _) andThen round(2)` compiles.